# Graded Betti numbers of monomial ideals and inclusions

Tags: combinatorics, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, monomial-ideals, betti-numbers

Let $I$ and $J$ be two monomial ideals in some polynomial ring $S=k[X_1,...,X_n]$. Furthermore, assume that $G(I)\subseteq G(J)$, where $G(I)$ denotes the minimal set of monomial generators of $I$, and likewise for $J$. Is it true that $\beta_{ij}(I)\le \beta_{ij}(J)$ for all $i,j$? This is certainly the case for $i=0$, since $\beta_{0j}$ is the number of elements in the minimal set of generators of degree $j$. I was also wondering if

$$\min\{j:\beta_{ij}(I)\neq 0\}\le \min\{j:\beta_{ij}(J)\neq 0\}$$

which would actually be a consequence of the previous statement if it were correct.

Comment: $G(I) \subseteq G(J)$ if and only if $I \subseteq J$, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JennyKenkel $G(I) \subseteq G(J)$ implies $I \subseteq J$, but not conversely: e.g. $I = (x^2)$, $J = (x)$

Comment: Anyways this kind of statement is easy to test, and here is a random counterexample: $I = (x_0x_2x_5, x_2x_3x_5, x_1x_2^2, x_1x_3x_5, x_4^2x_5, x_1^2x_5^2, x_0^2x_3x_5, x_0^2x_4^2, x_2x_3^3)$, $J = I + (x_1x_2x_5)$